How to format/align LaTeX markup using R?
Some packages such as knitr::kable() return relatively unformatted LaTeX markup such as in the example below:
\begin{tabular}{l|r|r|r|r|r}
& mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat\\
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90\\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.90\\
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108 & 93 & 3.85\\
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258 & 110 & 3.08\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360 & 175 & 3.15\\
\end{tabular}

How can I post-process this markup (e.g., by indenting nested environments and aligning on the "&" character) to achieve something more like the example below within R?
\begin{tabular}{l|r|r|r|r|r}
                     & mpg   & cyl & disp & hp  & drat \\
  Mazda RX4          & 21.0  & 6   & 160  & 110 & 3.90 \\
  Mazda RX4 Wag      & 21.0  & 6   & 160  & 110 & 3.90 \\
  Datsun 710         & 22.8  & 4   & 108  & 93  & 3.85 \\
  Hornet 4 Drive     & 21.4  & 6   & 258  & 110 & 3.08 \\
  Hornet Sportabout  & 18.7  & 8   & 360  & 175 & 3.15 \\
\end{tabular}

I'm wondering whether there is some ready-to-use LaTeX linter available or if the formatting needs to be done by hand.

https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent

Some editors, like TeXstudio, also have features to align columns.
